# How to Get Rid of Fields in a Dictionary of Dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm making this function on Python called `clean_data` that has...

- Parameters: A dictionary of dictionaries (all strings), and a list of strings containing the fields we care about.
- Returns: A dictionary of dictionaries with only the fields we care about, and with appropriate data types.

Fields we care about:

- Opponent  (string)
- Power Plays (“PP” -- int)

Sample input:

```
{"1/1" : {"opponent" : "BU", "X" : "3", "PP" : "0"},
 "1/2" : {"opponent" : "HC", "X" : "4", "PP" : "1"},
 "1/5" : {"opponent" : "BC", "X" : "8", "PP" : "0"}}
["opponent", "PP"]
```

Expected output:

```
{"1/1" : {"opponent" : "BU", "PP" : 0},
 "1/2" : {"opponent" : "HC", "PP" : 1},
 "1/5" : {"opponent" : "BC", "PP" : 0}}
```

Currently, I have

```
def clean_data(my_dict, field_ls):
  t = {}
  for x in field_ls:
      field = x
  for line in my_dict:
      for i in (my_dict[line]):
          if i != field:
             my_dict[line].pop(i)
```

However, I don't quite seem to get the output I want as the `pop(i)` isn't really working. How can I fix my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of popping keys, it seems it's easier (since there's only two of them) to select the key-value pairs you actually want.

```
def clean_data(my_dict):
    out = {}
    for k,d in my_dict.items():
        out[k] = {'opponent': str(d['opponent']), 'PP': int(d['PP'])}
    return out
```

Output:

```
{'1/1': {'opponent': 'BU', 'PP': 0},
 '1/2': {'opponent': 'HC', 'PP': 1},
 '1/5': {'opponent': 'BC', 'PP': 0}}
```

If you absolutely have to pop keys from a dictionary, then you can copy the keys using `list` constructor, then iterate over that list and pop unwanted fields

```
def clean_data(input_dict, dict_of_fields):
    my_dict = input_dict.copy()
    for d in my_dict.values():
        for field in list(d.keys()):
            if field not in dict_of_fields:
                d.pop(field)
            else:
                d[field] = dict_of_fields[field](d[field])
    return my_dict
```

Example:

```
sample_data = {"1/1" : {"opponent" : "BU", "X" : "3", "PP" : "0"},
 "1/2" : {"opponent" : "HC", "X" : "4", "PP" : "1"},
 "1/5" : {"opponent" : "BC", "X" : "8", "PP" : "0"}}
fields = {"opponent": str, "PP": int}
```

Output:

```
>>> print(clean_data(sample_data, fields))
{'1/1': {'opponent': 'BU', 'PP': 0}, 
 '1/2': {'opponent': 'HC', 'PP': 1}, 
 '1/5': {'opponent': 'BC', 'PP': 0}}
```

Comment: Thanks! What if I want to add a parameter that contains the list of fields I want because at the end I want to be able to select any fields out of a csv file, not just opponent and pp. Just for references, there are 6 fields in total: Opponent  (string), Win/Loss (“W/L” in the spreadsheet -- string), Goals (“G” -- int), Assists (“A” -- int), Power Plays (“PP” -- int), and Shots  Blocked (“BLK” -- int)

Comment: I meant that instead of hard coding opponent and pp into the function, I want to create a second parameter that is a list of the fields I want. For example, the function will look something like def clean_data(my_dict, list_of_fields), and list_of_fields = ["opponent", "pp"]. Do you get what I'm trying to say?

Comment: list_of_fields can also be ["G", "A", "BLK"], and the function will print out the rows under the fields. The fields are essentially columns of a csv file.

Comment: Thanks again! Very close, however, I still have to hardcode pp. Any chance you can make it so that there is no hard coding involved?

Comment: @PikachuYo you can pass another list for the integer types and iterate over it and convert corresponding keys to ints. or `list_of_fields` could be dicts with keys as needed keys and values as its types

Comment: @PikachuYo please see the update. does it work now?